# Unknown swift property in obj-c class

Tags: ios, swift

I have declare a property `var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D?` in my swift class
but i can't find this property in obj-c class. I have tried to add `@obj` before the class, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you make it non-optional it will work. (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the instance variable because coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D is not bridged with Objective C. Instead of declaring CLLocationCoordinate2D, you can declare latitude and longitude as NSNumber type and later using them make 2D coordinate.

```
var lat: NSNumber?
var lon: NSNumber?
```

And then assign value in your Objc Class as bellow:

```
switObject.lat = @3;
switObject.lon = @5;
```

For more information check this link [Cannot access property of Swift type from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366082/cannot-access-property-of-swift-type-from-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared an `optional` property (`?`), which is a pure `Swift` construct. They cannot be accessed by `Objective C` classes unless specifically bridged, like [`String` -> `NSString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221407/can-a-swift-optional-int-int-be-exposed-to-objective-c-via-bridging).

Answer (score 0):

Obj-C doesn't support optional structs. But if you make it non-optional, it compiles:

```
import CoreLocation

class Class : NSObject
{
    dynamic var coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D // no `?`: non-optional
    override init()
    {
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D() // it's not optional, so you must initialize `coordinate`
    }
}
```