# Swift variables not imported to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am using a Swift based project and have imported some Objective C files. Now I want my Swift code to work back in ObjC files. All goes well but unfortunately, Int, Float and Double attributes of classes are not available to Objective C class. Any idea why is this not being open to Objective C?

Swift Class:

```
class Station: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var Id : Int!
    var placeId : Int!
    var name : String!
    var stationDescription : String!
    var uuid : String!
    var major : Int?
    var minor : Int?
    var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var geoFenceRadius : Float?
    var questions : [Question]?


    }
```

Swift-Interface Generated Class:

```
@interface Station : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * _Null_unspecified name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * _Null_unspecified stationDescription;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * _Null_unspecified uuid;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<Question *> * _Nullable questions;
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id _Nullable)object;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aCoder;
+ (Station * _Nullable)stationWithDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * _Nonnull)dict placeUUID:(NSString * _Nullable)placeUUID;
+ (NSArray<Station *> * _Nullable)parseListFromDictionariesList:(NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *> * _Nonnull)dicts placeUUID:(NSString * _Nullable)placeUUID;
@end
```

This is the error while Id of object is Accessed. 
[image: Error while accessing Id of object]

Comment: Show us your code snippet and error logs if any.

Comment: @Saad : Are you using `@objc` keyword before `class` in swift?

Comment: @Poles nope. But tried this now and it didn't worked.

Comment: Found the reason. Objective Don't has replacement for Int that's why not imported

Comment: Only *optional* ints/floats are not imported.

Comment: well used @Poles trick by adding objc with every var and says "cannot use Objc Because type of this variable cannot be represented in Objective C" While it worked with String. Now used NSNumber and worked

Comment: Knew that only optionals are not imported but this case causing non-optionals as well

Comment: @Saad: I do not think so. Remove the `!` in `Int!` and the `?` in `Float?`  and watch the difference. – See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221407/can-a-swift-optional-int-int-be-exposed-to-objective-c-via-bridging.

Comment: well trying  var Id : Int = 10 didn't work either

Comment: ur swift version?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and my ints are imported as NSInteger's (using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.0.1). Anyway, I think it is a bad idea to use Id as a variable name, for two reasons: 1) in Swift, you should use non-capitalized variable names; and 2) Id is very similar to an Obj-C reserved keyword id. Try to rename your variable to something like itemID. Also remove the ! after the variable names and initialized them with 0 like this:

```
class Station: NSObject, NSCoding {

var itemID : Int = 0
var placeId : Int = 0
var name : String!
var stationDescription : String!
var uuid : String!
var major : Int = 0
var minor : Int = 0
var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
var geoFenceRadius : Float = 0.0
var questions : [Question]?


}
```

This is causing all your problems, as Martin pointed out earlier.

Comment: will check it tomo